# How to list out the Telephony Provider and add a Telephony Provider through powershell

Tags: powershell

I tried using telephon.cpl which just opens the Phone and Modem options but doesn't go to the Advanced tab. I'm looking for the selected TSP in the Advanced and if it's any other than a desired one, say X, I've to set it to X. I searched across many blogs but unable to find this anywhere.

This is the setting which I want to access through Powershell:

[image]

I want to access these options and check which is the presently selected option through Powershell

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't go ? Is it disabled ? Can you edit your question with a screenshot of your problem ?

Comment: Do you know how to do it in C#?  If so, can you point me at a reference?